# Calculate a variance

Tags: statistics, covariance

> > Consider
> >     $$
> > \hat{\theta_2}=\frac{n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{n\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2}
> > $$
> >     Show that $Var(\hat{\theta_2})=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})^2}.$

Here we consider the linear modell
$$
y_i=\theta_1+\theta_2x_i+u_i, Var(u_i)=\sigma^2
$$
where the $x_i$ are not arbitrary but the $y_i$ and the $y_i$ are indepedent.

So I tried to calculate it:

$$
Var(\hat{\theta_2})=\frac{1}{(n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2)^2}Var(n\sum x_iy_i-\sum x_i\sum y_i)\\
=\frac{1}{(n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2)^2}Var(\sum nxy_iy_i)-Var(\sum x_i\sum y_i)\\
=\frac{1}{(n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2)^2}n^2\sigma^2\sum x_i^2-n\sigma^2 (\sum x_i)^2\\
=\frac{1}{(n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2)^2}\sigma^2 n(n(\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2)\\
=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum x_i^2-\frac{1}{n}(\sum x_i)^2}
$$

But thats not what I wanted to show.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is perfectly okay, because $$\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2=\sum x_i^2-2\sum x_i \bar{x}+\sum\bar{x}^2=\sum x_i^2-2n\bar{x}^2+n\bar{x}^2=\sum x_i^2-n\bar{x}^2\\=\sum x_i^2-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum x_i\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you! One more question: Why are $n\sum x_iy_i$ and $\sum x_i\sum y_i$ independet so that I can calculate the variance of it as sum of the variances?

Comment: $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$ where $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: Sorry, do not see what you mean.

Comment: What I tried to convey is that the Covariance must be $0$. They need not be independent, but has to be uncorrelated.

Comment: I got that, but that means that I have to calculate $E(\sum nx_iy_i\cdot\sum x_i\sum y_i)-E(\sum nx_i y_i)E(\sum x_i\sum y_i)$. Is that more easy?

Comment: Since you have that linear model, it is certainly not difficult.

Comment: Nevertheless: Do not see that this is $0$. Can you show it please?

Comment: Actually, I think, in your calculation you have made a mistake by writing $Var((...)-(...))=Var(...)-Var(...)$, try to redo it using the correct formula, I think the covariance will not be $0$ but still the final answer will come out to be as it is.

Comment: I think one has to argue that they are independent... but i do not know how. It does not work with the covariance.